# Problemas con Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php

Estoy formando un php para un consultorio, en esta parte se agregan citas pero a la hora de realizar la funcion sale el siguiente error:

> Warning: Undefined array key "citfecha" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "cithora" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 9
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "citPaciente" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 10
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "citMedico" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 11
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "citConsultorio" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 12
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "citestado" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Undefined array key "citobservaciones" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php-medico\agregarcitas.php on line 14

El php con las lineas con error son las siguientes :

```php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    $citfecha = $_POST['citfecha'];
    $cithora = $_POST['cithora'];
    $citPaciente =  $_POST['citPaciente'];
    $citMedico =  $_POST['citMedico'];
    $citConsultorio =  $_POST['citConsultorio'];
    $citestado =  $_POST['citestado'];
    $citobservaciones =  $_POST['citobservaciones'];
    $mensaje='';

if(empty($citfecha) or empty($cithora)  or empty($citConsultorio) or empty($citPaciente) or empty($citestado)or empty($citMedico)){
        $mensaje.= 'Por favor rellena todos los datos correctamente'."<br />";
    }
    else{   
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=centromedico','root','');
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo "Error: ". $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }
    if($mensaje==''){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare(
            'INSERT INTO citas values(null, :citfecha,:cithora,:citPaciente,:citMedico,:citConsultorio,:citestado,:citobservaciones)');

        $statement ->execute(array(
            ':citfecha'=>$citfecha,
            ':cithora'=>$cithora,
            ':citPaciente'=>$citPaciente,
            ':citMedico'=>$citMedico,
            ':citConsultorio'=>$citConsultorio,
            ':citestado'=>$citestado,
            ':citobservaciones'=>$citobservaciones
        ));

        #print_r($statement->errorInfo());exit;

        header('Location: citas.php');
    }
}
require 'vista/agregarcitas_vista.php';
```

Les agradesco me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿y el formulario HTML como es?  Porque esta claro que no coinciden los datos y nombres enviados con lo que esperas recibir.  ¿Ya usas el atributo **name=** para nombrar a los inputs? (los **id=** no sirven si estas lanzando un submit de un formulario)

Answer (score 1):

Te está diciendo cada error concreto y en la línea en que se produce... deberías ser capaz de entenderlo y solucionarlo por ti mismo. Pero bueno, siempre hay una primera vez.

Los errores son todos del mismo tipo:

`Warning: Undefined array key`

Significa que estás intentando acceder a un elemento de un array mediante un índice que no existe en ese array.

Seguramente te está pasando porque no estás enviando esos datos por `POST`, y, por tanto, no los tienes en la variable superglobal `$_POST`. Comprueba que el formulario tenga `method="post"`, y que los inputs del mismo tengan correctamente la etiqueta `name`.

Además, podrías hacer las asignaciones así:

```
$citfecha = isset($_POST['citfecha']) ? $_POST['citfecha'] : '';
```